# Offline entity creation JScript and IndexedDb

Tags: javascript, sql-server, indexeddb

I have a website with an offline datastore (IndexedDb) and I have a couple of entities that can be related to each other by foreign key, lets call them TableA and TableB. While offline I want to create a new TableB and have TableA join to it by a foreign key.

```
TableA.TableBId
```

What is the best way to persist this back to the Db once online again and keep the relationships. The tables in the database have an identity column that is used for the Id but this is obviously created in the database not in the front end application. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: I have played around with using temporary GUID's in the front end to do the relationships but it gets complicated once this all persists back to the real Db backend, I'm thinking perhaps I could change the back end to use Guids and then front and back can create new entities ???

Comment: 1..Are you using PouchDB as an interface to IndexedDB?? 2. It is not clear whether you want to persist it back to server db or what exactly and also what do you mean by keeping relationships .. You mean once you app is online, you want to delete all content of TableB but when app is offline then again same things will happen .. Could you please elaborate ..

Comment: Nope not using PouchDB, I'll have to check that out.
Yes I want to persist TableA with its relationship to TableB back to server db. before that happens TableB doesn't have an id as its not been able to get one from the server until it goes online. I don't want to delete anything

Comment: backend is MSSQL by the way

Comment: Just to let you know - You can consider PouchDB, it provided a seamless synchronization with a server database CouchDB ..

Comment: For solution of your problem - more information is required, existing information looks relatively less .. If you could create an example (not code but at least explanation) then it would be help in helping you ..

Comment: I'll take a look at PouchDB but I don't think that integrates with MSSQL

Comment: Yes, I also think same, but have a search ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I managed this.

I created guids in the offline ui end and tacked those onto my entities and included this new guid in the actual server side table. I could then perform look ups on the entity using a combination of the guid and the real identity column.

Sorry if this isn't very clear but its a tricky thing to explain really without seeing what is going on along with diagrams!

Comment: I understand and agree.